# Fixing deprecated files

Tags: polymer, runtime-error, polymer-1.0, deprecated, console.log

I'm trying to eliminate the console warnings (of deprecation) from the `iron-flex-layout` element.

When I load my app, I get the following errors in the console:

> iron-shadow-flex-layout.html:12 This file is deprecated. Please use `iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html`, and one of the specific dom-modules instead
>   (anonymous)
>
> iron-shadow-flex-layout.html:12
>   iron-flex-layout.html:14 This file is deprecated. Please use `iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html`, and one of the specific dom-modules instead
>   (anonymous)
>
> iron-flex-layout.html:14
>   iron-fit-behavior.html:221 /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.

When I inspect the file paths, I see the following:

> http://localhost:8080/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-shadow-flex-layout.html
>
> http://localhost:8080/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html
>
> http://localhost:8080/bower_components/iron-fit-behavior/iron-fit-behavior.html

I am reluctant to go tinkering around and manually deleting files in my `bower_components` directory.

So, how can I fix these errors? What is the recommended best practice?

Edit

[Here is the deprecated file on Github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/classes/iron-flex-layout.html). Line 14 writes the console warning. **But this deprecated file is not being imported anywhere in the app**. (I know because I did a global search on the string `iron-flex-layout/classes` and, separately, on `iron-shadow-flex-layout.html`). Instead, I have done as the warning suggests; I imported `iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html` everywhere instead. But the warning persists nevertheless.

I assume the element owners and Google overlords want to retain the console warnings in place (and not accept a PR which removes it). So, what is the best practice? Live with the warnings? (It doesn't seem quite right to edit my local copy and just comment out the warnings.) Or should I do something else? (Maybe there is another option I'm not aware of.)

Edit2

per @tony19:

> I recommend setting a breakpoint in the deprecated file (on the `console.log()` line) to see who's importing it. – *tony19*

So now, I'm using this:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/classes/iron-flex-layout.html

```
<script>
  console.warn('This file is deprecated. Please use `iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html`, and one of the specific dom-modules instead');
  debugger;
</script>
```

I'm seeing some information appear when the app reaches the breakpoint. But nothing so far indicates what's causing the import of the `iron-flex-layout` element. Or what to do to fix it.

Is there a command or something that can log what file imported another file? I've looked all over for how I might accomplish that. Could anyone please describe in detail what that might look like?

Answer (score 1):

The warning indicates that an HTML file in your source or dependencies is importing `../iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html`, which is deprecated. The import must be in your tree somewhere, or else the warning wouldn't appear. I recommend setting a breakpoint on the [`console.log()` line of the deprecated file](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/b2345f7/classes/iron-flex-layout.html#L14) to track down the offender.

If you're in control of the offending element that imports this deprecated file, you can update the import to use `iron-flex-layout-classes.html` that the warning recommends. Otherwise, you can petition the maintainer of the offending element to update their dependencies (or submit a PR ;).

Comment: Yes. That was my analysis as well. But I'm not importing the deprecated file. Please read my new edit to the question. I think it clarifies my situation a bit.

Comment: I recommend setting a breakpoint in the deprecated file (on the `console.log()` line) to see who's importing it.

Comment: Is there a command or something that can log what file imported another file? I've looked all over for how I might accomplish that. Could you give a little more detail what that might look like?

Comment: Oh. I see it now. There is a *call stack* listed in the console when I add the `debugger;` instruction line. But the calling function is `(anonymous)`. That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today and thought the same thing. However, diving a bit deeper I found a few third party components were using paper-styles/paper-styles which called in iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html. The reference it'd be there somewhere I'm certain. Hope that helps.